# Creating a function to calculate the log of a number without built-in methods

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the log base 2 of a number without using built-in methods, but having some trouble doing so for numbers between 0-1.

For example, for numbers greater than 1, the program returns the value fine. However, for input like 0.5, the function should return -1 or for input 0.25, the function should return -2. Currently it just returns that the value is between -1 and 0 as if the function is returning a decimal value.

How is this possible without using the buit-in method log?

Code:

```
count = 0

curr = 1

if (number < 1):
    
    'Code to compute values less than 1'

while (curr < number):
    curr = curr * 2
    count += 1

if (curr == number):
    return str(count)
else:
    return "in between " + str(count - 1) + " and " + str(count)
```

Comment: If you initialize `count` to `0`, and then you only increase it with `count += 1`, you cannot expect `count-1` to ever be `-2`. There should probably be sometimes where you decrease `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
        if number < 1:
            while curr < number:
               curr = curr / 2
               count -= 1
```

Btw, you don't have to (and shouldn't) use parentheses in loops in Python

EDIT: Also note, that it only works for base 2 and it's powers due to floating-point precision error! You should not compare floats directly, but using `math.isclose()` function